# Problem with using a timer to update progressbar

Tags: java, swing

I have implement a timer to run a progress bar as follows

```
 public class UpdateOnline extends JInternalFrame {

//UI related code goes here

        class jbutton_proceed_action implements ActionListener {

                public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
                    int result = -1;
                    Timer time = new Timer(50, updateBar);
                    time.start();
                    result = doUpload("bulk");
                }
            }


        ActionListener updateBar = new ActionListener() {

                public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent ae) {
                    int val = jProgressBar1.getValue();
                    jProgressBar1.setValue(++val);

                }
            };

        }
```

what is happening is when I clicked on a button called upload, it performed action in class jbutton_proceed_action. The method called `doUpload` upload data to a database which take mere than 2 minutes time to finished. My problem was eventhough I have start the timer before calling to doUpload method progressbar doesnot start running untill doUpload method finished. Can some one pls help me to solve that problem.

I need to run the prgressbar mean while the uplod occurs

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is because `doUpload` is running on the Swing (UI) EDT (event dispatch thread) and blocking it. Using [SwingWorker](http://download.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/concurrency/worker.html) is one way to handle the long-running task and still play nice. Make sure that all UI updates/manipulation *only* happens from the EDT -- the previous link (to the SwingWorker trail) contains the details.

Answer (score 2):

You doUpload is running on the UI thread, causing it to block.

execute the doUpload in a new thread

http://download.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/concurrency/worker.html

Answer (score 0):

all you need is here:

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SwingWorker